# Not able to select element from a drop down

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have very hard time to select an element drop down in selenium web driver with C#. I tried and googled a lot. Nothing is working out. Can some one pls help?

My code is

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("header_Menu1Container"));
SelectElement se = new SelectElement(element);
se.SelectByValue("Add New Action`enter code here`");
```

and I tried using selectByText as well.

HTML code:

```
<div id="header_Menu1Container" class="MenuStyle" style="width: 100%">
   <ul class="adxm menu_htb level1">
      <li>
         <a class="submenu" href="/ad07.asp">
            <ul class="level2">
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="submenu" href="/ca10.asp">
            <span class="text">Actions</span>
            <span class="right2"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="level2">
            <li>
               <a class="submenu" title="Add New Action" href="/ca11c.asp">
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="submenu" title="All Actions" href="/ca10.asp">
                  <span class="text">All Actions</span>
               </a>
```

Comment: You cannot use SelectElement  class since it is not a select tag. what is the target tag?

Comment: My target is Add new action    <div id="header_Menu1Container" class="MenuStyle" style="width: 100%">
<ul class="adxm menu_htb level1">
<li>
<a class="submenu" href="/ad07.asp">
<ul class="level2">
</li>
<li>
<a class="submenu" href="/ca10.asp">
<span class="text">Actions</span>
<span class="right2"></span>
</a>
<ul class="level2">
<li>
<a class="submenu" title="Add New Action" href="/ca11c.asp">
</li>
<li>
<a class="submenu" title="All Actions" href="/ca10.asp">
<span class="text">All Actions</span>
</a>

Comment: Are you sure that HTML is correct/complete? There are mismatched tags, etc.

Comment: I have pasted above, main question description. Pls let me know if that is also have mismatches

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SELECT` tag in the HTML you provided and it looks like it's one of those simulated `SELECT`s... basically other tags formatted to look like a `SELECT`. Anyway, you will have to click other elements one at a time... first click the `SELECT`-looking tag and then click the desired option in the dropdown. From the code snippet you provided, it looks like you want the "Add New Action" option.

We may have to do some trial and error since I can't see the page but something like this should get you headed in the right direction.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("header_Menu1Container")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']")).Click();
```

You may need a slight pause after initially clicking the dropdown. If so, you can use the `WebDriverWait` code below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("header_Menu1Container")).Click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']"))).Click();
```

---

EDIT

Sorry, I didn't see a language tag and I just coded up Java. I just realized that you were wanting C# so I edited the answer.

Without more of the surrounding HTML or a link to the page, this is about as good as I can get. The basic premise is that this is not a `SELECT`. In order to make it work, you will have to click the outer element to open the dropdown and then click one of the elements in the dropdown... both using `.click()`.

---

EDIT 2

More new info... what you need is to hover over the Action menu to expose the submenu and then click on the Add New Action link.

```
WebElement actionsMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("header_Menu1Container"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(actionsMenu).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']")).click();
```

Comment: Even I am surprised that no select. It has Div and then class later span tag... Thank you for your response. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have tried  below , getting  error -An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll  . But it clicked on another submenu . I have menu like Actions hazards  incidents  audits. it clicked on audits. driver.FindElement(By.Id("header_Menu1Container")).Click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']"))).Click();

Comment: What line did it throw on?

Comment: on this wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']"))).Click();

Comment: Ah... that's because, as you said, it clicked on the wrong top level menu. You will need to change the first `.click()` to click the right top level menu... then the `wait` and `.click()` will work.

Comment: Actually I want to go to Actions-> Add new action..  header_Menu1Container") that I was using is the Menubar id.. so, I want to put my mouse on Actions and then go to Add new action and click. The problem with finding Actions drop down is . That Actions itself is a link. So I cannot click. How to identify that. No id. Class name is same like the other items .

Comment: I am still breaking my head on this. Better than yestedray though. It is clicking on submenu I have asked for (Actions) and it is also clicking on Next submenu(Hazards) and then selecting a item(add new hazard) from that dropdown. Not sure why is it even going to next submenu also.It is getting difficult because sibmenu has no id. In this

Comment: Mehod1
           Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            IWebElement actionsMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
            action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Perform();
             driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='Add New Action']")).Click();

Comment: Method 2
             IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Actions"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
            IWebElement subElement = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Add New Action"));
            subElement.Click();

Comment: Question: Do we need to identify Main menubar, then submenu then item we need. or if I just explore submenu and select item which I need is enough??

Comment: I'm not sure since I can't see the page. You need to think of this like a user would. What does the user need to do to access the link you want to click and then code what the user would have to do. They might need to hover or click or ??? elements in a specific sequence... do that with code.

Comment: HEYYYYYY! working now. Seems like I somehow gave wrong Xpath. . Now it is working...Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            IWebElement actionsMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]"));
            action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span")).Click();
        }

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If you would, please accept this (or whichever) as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Directly find out the xpath of the element you wanted to select from the drop-down.
--------------------or--------------------------------

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("----------"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("-----------"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if("Germany".equals(option.getText()))
        option.click();
```

}
------------------or---------------------------------------

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Select country1 = new Select(country);
    country1.selectByVisibleText("Canada");
```

Comment: when I directly used the Xpath, I am getting Element not visible exception - cannot click on the element. .will try other options. driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@id='header_Menu1Container']/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a/span")).Click();

Comment: If the XPath works for you then just make sure you click the top level menu first. Selenium won't interact with an element if it's not visible... it better simulates a user's experience. Once you click the top level menu, then click the XPath element... that should work.